# Significance of overly explicit scene at the start of the film?

Tags: analysis, antichrist

Regarding the movie [Antichrist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0870984/?ref_=nv_sr_1) by Lars von Trier: **Why is there is an openly explicit pornographic scene at the beginning of the movie**? Has this sequence any aesthetic or stylistic purpose aside from shocking the audience?

Comment: Probably not...Lars Van Trier was open in stating that the movie was *intentionally provocative*.

Comment: I wonder same about game of thrones though. great story, probably could be better without pornographic scenes. Don't get me wrong, I love porn. ;)

Comment: Isn't it where the baby dies? That would totally justify it. The selfishness, the blame, the guilt, etc.